# Estimation with MCMC

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, intuition, point-estimation

I would like to ask some high-view questions about MCMC. I do not have a specific example, I just want to get a general intuitive idea.

Suppose I have a data set $X$ and a rather complex model with parameters $\theta$. I would like to fit the model and find the parameters. How can I do that with MCMC? If I already have the data, why do I continue to generate samples?

a. Am I generating data samples $X'$ and then fit the model to get an estimate $\tilde{\theta}$? But why I have to do this if I already have the data?

b. Or am I generating samples of the parameters $\theta'$ (using data $X$, I don't know how though) then use the mode or mean of the posterior distribution $\mathbb{E}_{p(\theta'|X)}(\theta)$?

c. I have seen a lot of places use the term "Metropolis-Hastings update" (for example [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMCglmm/vignettes/Overview.pdf) at page 4). I wonder what they mean by the updates? Is it the next parameter sample $\theta'$ sampled from the algorithm or is it the updated parameters $\tilde{\theta}$ that I estimated from the sampled data $X'$?

If all my above guesses are incorrect, what is the correct one?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: a) No, you do not sample from the data space but from the parameter space. b) yes, you do sample from the space of possible/credible values of $\theta\. That is the magic of MCMC c) In  Byes statistics you rely on your beliefs before seeing the data, the so called prior and then you updated your beliefs in light of prior and the data to form your posterior beliefs. Hence updating.

Comment: @Bernhard Thank you very much for your comments! The problem is clear to me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MCMC stands for Markov Chain Monte Carlo and is a method that can estimate or compute different distributions. In MCMC you create a sequence of random variables under the [Markov assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property) (a
Markov Chain) and you modify that sequence so that you can use the generated random variables for [Monte Carlo sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method). Monte Carlo sampling can be used to compute quantities such as the posterior mean, the posterior mode, etc. The Metropolis-Hastings algorithm is an MCMC algorithm to obtain samples, $\theta^{(n)}$, from a desired distribution, such as the posterior distribution. The posterior distribution tells you what is the probability distribution of the parameters $\theta$ in a model given a set of realized measurements, $X = x$. The measurements are assumed to be a realization of a set of random variables $X$, that is generated by said model and its parameters $\theta$.

Applying the Metropolis Algorithm to the posterior distribution gives:

1. Given $\theta^{(n)}$
2. Sample $\theta'$ from $\mathcal{N}(\theta';\theta^{(n)}, \Sigma)$
3. Set $$\theta^{(n+1)} = \begin{cases}\theta' \quad \text{with probability } \rho(\theta', \theta^{(n)}) \\ \theta^{(n)} \quad \text{with probability } 1- \rho(\theta', \theta^{(n)})
    \end{cases}$$
   where
   $$
   \rho(\theta', \theta^{(n)}) = \min \left(1, \frac{p(X=x|\theta')p(\theta')}{p(X=x|\theta^{(n)})p(\theta^{(n)})}\right)
   $$

Running this for sufficiently many samples, the generated samples will then be distributed according to the posterior distribution
$$
\theta^{(n)} \sim p(\theta | X=x)
$$
The interpretation of a Metropolis step is that for each proposed $\theta'$ you compute the probability of observing the generated $X$, from the model and $\theta'$, with what you have $x$. If that probability is higher than the corresponding value for $\theta^{(n)}$, you accept that sample. But even if the proposed value $\theta'$ yields a lower probability, there is still a chance that you accept that sample.

Running this for a long time, the samples $\theta^{(n)}$ will concentrate around regions where $p(\theta | X=x)$ have high probability.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! That is the clearest answer I have read. I just want to ask one last thing about your last sentence, you say that finally $\theta^{(n)} \sim p(\theta|X = x)$ but you also say that $\theta^{(n)}$ will concentrate around regions where $p(\theta|X = x)$ have high probability. Are these two statements equivalent?

Comment: Not equivalent but almost. The former is the technical meaning of the latter. The latter is the intuition of the former :)